# File-level less variables

Tags: less, bem

I want to define block name at once at head of its file

```
@block: widget-a;
```

And then use it in selectors

```
.@{block} {
    // my styles
}
```

But I can't do it when I have more than one block. Variable `@block` takes the last value and it breaks my selectors

```
// file a.less
@block: widget-a;
.@{block} {
    // styles for widget-a
}

// file b.less
@block: widget-b;
.@{block} {
    // styles for widget-b
}
```

Both rulesets there got the block `.widget-b` in spite of that is different files. Is there a way to persist name for each block?

Here is a gist: https://gist.github.com/just-boris/a86f3646f48683a9bf17 which can be built and reproduce it. I use `less 2.3.0`

Comment: I don't think you can. When multiple values are defined for the same variable, the [last one wins](http://lesscss.org/features/#variables-feature-lazy-loading).

Comment: In addition to the answer below, here's nice Less variables [tutorial](http://earthli.com/news/view_article.php?id=2965) which reveals common beginner pitfalls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure why you have to use the same variable name twice?
You code does not compile:

you code:

```
// file a.less
@block: ~".widget-a";
@{block}: {
    // styles for widget-a
}
```

should be:

```
// file a.less
@block: ~".widget-a";
@{block} {
    // styles for widget-a
}
```

can be rewritten to, see [variable-interpolation](http://lesscss.org/features/#variables-feature-variable-interpolation):

```
@block: widget-a;
.@{block} {
    // styles for widget-a
    color: red;
}
```

As already mentioned by @harry, when defining the same variable twice in the same scope, the last declaration wins. You could wrap your code in a mixin or use [namespaces](http://lesscss.org/features/#features-overview-feature-namespaces-and-accessors):

```
// file a.less
.a() {
@block: widget-a;
.@{block} {
    // styles for widget-a
    color: red;
}
}
.a();

// file b.less
.b() {
@block: widget-b;
.@{block} {
    // styles for widget-b
    color:blue;
}
}
.b();
```

outputs:

```
.widget-a {
  color: red;
}
.widget-b {
  color: blue;
}
```

Comment: True, namespaces or different files for each widget are possible options.

Comment: Semicolon after selector was a typo. Now I've updated example.

Comment: Solution with mixins seems to be good, looks like IIFE in javascript

Comment: And just in case, there's less verbose solution: [gist](https://gist.github.com/seven-phases-max/8e51863434b5f27da360#file-28168508-less).